# Neither control key is not registered with Anthy installed

Tags: keyboard, xinput

I have a very annoying problem with a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 install. For some reason control keys usually do not register. There seem to be no event given by `xev`. By usual, I mean most of the time. Sometimes for some time they both work for a minute, and then again they stop working.

I have an Asus ux31a laptop, bought in Japan, so it has a Japanese layout. I sometimes type Japanese, so I need anthy installed, and I'm wondering is somehow that is at fault now.

In language input, I have selected `default` as the "Keyboard input method system" (as instructed in here: [Input methods after upgrade to 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362170/input-methods-after-upgrade-to-13-10)), I have also tried `ibus`, but I did not see the difference.

In text entry, I have 2 input sources configured currently, Japanese, and Japanese (Anthy), Japanese being the primary one. Usually I have my native language setup as well, but currently no, I want to find the culprit first.

When control keys work, `xev` shows the codes to be:

```
jlumme@zenbk:~$ xev | grep -i keypress -A2
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 15177433, (94,113), root:(1002,921),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
--
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 15181339, (94,113), root:(1002,921),
    state 0x0, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
```

`xmodmap` shows:

```
jlumme@zenbk:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep 37
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
jlumme@zenbk:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep 105
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
```

What puzzles me is that it is seemingly random when it works and when it doesn't, I'm happily browsing the web, and able to shortcuts to open new tabs and close, until I don't, without any kind of clear indication as to what triggered the change. It doesn't have to be the browser, it can be any text editor as well, same thing.

In `gnome-tweak-tool` I have disabled the `control-key-position` setting, also I have tried to force it to bottom left, but no help.

Comment: Have you tried with a Live CD? And, the problem is solved if you remove Anthy?

Comment: Can you isolate the problem to Ubuntu 13.10? That is, does the behaviour manifest if you install osx or windows? Do follow Braiam's suggestions before mine.

Comment: No, this problem is not resolved by removing anthy. Also, Im sure this is not a hardware problem, it was working fine with 13.04 for long time, and started happening after upgrade to 13.10. I did a fresh install for another reason, but the problem persists.